# How i can set datastore index configuration in google cloud via NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to run GQL query on my datastore.
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE model = @model AND date >= @date
```

But there's error like:

```
You need an index to execute this query.
```

In google api documentation i found nothing about indexes for nodejs.
How i can set this indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly as of today the `gcd` tool doesn't support automatic index generation for languages using the JSON interface (like Node.js or Ruby).

A workaround is the manually define your index in `<your-dataset-directory>/WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="product" ancestor="false">
        <property name="model" direction="asc" />
        <property name="date" direction="asc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

See the [Index Configuration](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig) section of the datastore documentation for more details.